# Настройка dhcpd с нуля на CentOS

Tags: dhcp, centos

Возникла необходимость настроить dhcp сервер на CentOS.В сети будет несколько компьютеров и возможно расширение.В общем то нужно просто настроить сервер так чтобы он выдавал адреса с 192.168.1.10 по 192.168.1.254Пробовал пользоваться всякими руководствами из сети, но все что получал при старте - FAILED. Просьба либо помочь с конфигом, либо дать ссылку на толковое руководство.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# dhcpd.conf## задаю DNS, чтоб их прописать автоматом клиентамoption domain-name-servers 87.237.112.10, 77.241.40.178;default-lease-time 3600;max-lease-time 86400;ddns-update-style none;# описание первой подсетки с пулом динамически раздаваемых адресов# от 192.168.55.140 до .180subnet 192.168.55.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {#  interface vr0;   range 192.168.55.140 192.168.55.180;   option routers 192.168.55.1;}# аналогично для второй подсеткиsubnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {#  interface xl0;   range 192.168.1.140 192.168.1.180;   option routers 192.168.1.1;}host one {  hardware ethernet 00:1d:22:33:44:55;  fixed-address 192.168.55.2;}host two {  hardware ethernet 00:1d:33:44:55:66;  fixed-address 192.168.55.3;}host wifirouter {   hardware ethernet 00:1c:33:44:55:66;   fixed-address 192.168.1.2;   option routers 192.168.1.1;}
```

Файл получен из dhcpd.conf.sample путем редактирования - удаления ненужного и добавлением нужных пунктов.

P.S. файл с FreeBSD с ISC dhcpd, но принцип примерно везде одинаков.

P.P.S. если при старте получаете

> Пробовал пользоваться всякими руководствами из сети, но все что получал при старте - FAILED.

то обязательно смотрите логи. Увидите там, что наверняка

- или нет файла конфигурации,
- или он некорректен (легко пропустить точку с запятой или закрывающую фигурную скобку).
- Ну, или проблема в чем-то другом, но это будет описано.

Логи искать где-то в /var/log/

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то 4 первых опции обязательны? А дальше идет объявление 2х пулов и 2 статических хоста?

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что они 100% обязательны, но мне было спокойнее задать, чем пользоваться значениями "по умолчанию". Да, дальше два пула и три хоста. Причем внимание - хосты не совсем статик. Я бы даже сказал, что совсем не статик. А динамически получают фиксированный IP по MAC-адресу. Это удобно тем, что всегда можно при знании IP обратиться к ПК напрямую. Интерфейсы я закомментировал, но вообще можно dhcpd пускать на конретных интерфейсах.

Comment: Да прошу прощения, не статические, а резервированные (по крайней мере, в Windows оно так называется). Благодарю, надеюсь запустится.

Comment: Увы не запустилось. лог от dhcpd отсутствует.

Comment: Лога не быть не может! Ищите. Может писать в какой-нибудь /var/log/messages или daemon.log

Comment: Да, действительно теперь все правильно. )

Comment: Так в чем конкретно была проблема?